# How to display page-template name in wordpress page

Tags: wordpress

**1 - I want to know the logic of how template-name comes automatically in WordPress page 's drop-down**

**2 - Just write in template-page.php and how fetch template-name in WordPress back-end page from template-page.php**

Thank you

Comment: You mean to say that if you template name template-first into the code it should we display front end for which page you are using it?

Answer (score 1):

if I am not wrong then your questions related to creating the template then you need to create a file and then start

```
 /**
     * Template Name: My Awesome Custom Page
     * This is the most generic template file in a WordPress theme
     * and one of the two required files for a theme (the other being style.css).
     * It is used to display a page when nothing more specific matches a query.
     * E.g., it puts together the home page when no home.php file exists.
     *
     * @link http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy
     *
     * @package WordPress
     * @subpackage Twenty_Sixteen
     * @since Twenty Sixteen 1.0
     */
```

After then just copy paste the code of your index.php file and it will show in admin into the page section. [check tutorials](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/creating-custom-page-templates-in-wordpress/)

Comment: I already know the whole process of how to create, how its assign, and how it to use but, i want to know the logic that how's it possible that the template's name is shown in page's drop-down without writing and code or anything can you help about it ?

Answer (score 0):

For create custom template create file in your activated theme's folder. fo example if your custom template name is "home_custom_template".
Write code inside your file :

```
    <?php
    /*
    Template Name: home_custom_template
    */
    get_header();
    ?>
          /*
             Your Php and html code here...
          */

 <?php get_footer();?>
```

1))

```
     /*
        Template Name: home_custom_template
     */
```

this code define to wordpress this is template.

2))
 Create new page In wordpress, right side of page one dropdown for template. you can find your template there. So, choose your custom template and publish page.

You can find more informations here : [How to create a custom template](http://www.expand2web.com/blog/custom-page-template-wordpress/)